# What is the purpose of nutmeg in apple zucchini bread?

Tags: bread, flavor

I have looked up Apple Zucchini Bread recipes and most of them call for nutmeg. Does this make a big difference in the taste? I have not used nutmeg very much in my cooking or baking. All of my other zucchini bread recipes do not call for nutmeg, not even my apple sauce zucchini bread. Can this be left out and not affect the taste?

Comment: Do you like nutmeg? That's sort of the important question here. If you don't like nutmeg or you're ambivalent to it, don't use it. If you haven't tried it before and are curious, try it. I personally love it and think it adds a lovely depth of flavor to recipes but there are certainly some that it fits better with than others.

Answer (score 3):

Of course the apple zucchini bread will taste different with nutmeg as opposed to without. As the nutmeg is added solely to add nutmeg flavor, the bread will otherwise be fine.

It just comes down to your personal taste as to whether you choose to use it or not.

Comment: Nutmeg is a common ingredient in apple spice recipes (eg. Apple pie, mulled apple cider, etc.) +1 if you don't like don't use it. But if you don't have it I don't think it's a game changer.

Comment: I made two batches. I used the nutmeg in one and left it out of the other one. Both turned out really good. Thank you for the advice.